# Need help on tableau image carousel

Tags: tableau-api

I want to add an image carousel on a dashboard in Tableau. Around 3-4 images in slideshow from right to left. How does that work? Any insights would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by image carousel ? You want static images one after the other going from left to right ? 
Is that what you meant ?

Comment: Yes. i just want it as a slideshow within lets say a narrow strip in a dashboard. Should i create a web page with image slider and use weblink to embed it or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You can select image pane on dashboard and give the image to that pane. you will have to create 4-5 of such panes with different images and then adjust them on the dashboard from left to rights. Try making them floating. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Still dont understand. What is the image pane?

Comment: I can add only static images but i dont know how to make them move like a slideshow ( left to right)

Comment: ok, if you want to move them,then you have to go with your earlier suggestion of creating a web page. Cause I don't think tableau allows timer and rotating strip of images.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a picture slideshow in Tableau is not supported in a native way (purposely I assume) and I think there are several reasons you should reconsider your idea.

1. Tableau is a data visualisation tool and not PowerPoint. You should stick to visualising your data and not create a full on multi-media dashboard that distracts from the important points you want to present
2. If you need to display pictures that's fine (and possible) but having them changed independently of the data, doesn't seem to add any additional value to a dashboard and should be better done in a different place eg. the website you embed the dashboard in.
3. If you really want to have animations and moving parts in your dashboard and consider it a necessary feature to proof your point, the only way is to do what you already mentioned, create this slider in an external website and embed it in the dashboard. This however seems like a weird idea as well since if you do embed it in a website, it would be way easier to just do the slider there. If the dashboard is intended to be used locally however, you cannot guarantee that the user will have internet connection, which would mean that it cannot be consumed in a way you intended it to be consumed.